# Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext. Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, filenotfoundexception, abbyy

I am trying to deploy in tomcat server then I am getting this error.

Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/socr-microservices]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
... 43 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.my.BackendApplication]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/abbyy/FCEngine/IReadStream.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:189)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:745)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:420)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:175)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:155)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:97)
at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5219)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
... 44 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/abbyy/FCEngine/IReadStream.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:199)
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.getClassReader(SimpleMetadataReader.java:55)
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.(SimpleMetadataReader.java:49)
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103)
at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.createMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:86)
at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:73)
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:81)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:696)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getInterfaces(ConfigurationClassParser.java:1024)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processInterfaces(ConfigurationClassParser.java:386)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:332)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:199)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:304)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:207)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:175)

Comment: `class path resource [com/abbyy/FCEngine/IReadStream.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist at ` seems like the error and pretty clear. Not all your classes are available.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.